# Pass reference to form component the directive is applied on in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, model, components, directive

I have to access $error property in one of my controller methods. I do it like this:

```
<input name="myinput"
       my-directive="{{doSomethingWith(myform.myinput)}}"
      // other
/>
```

Unfortunatelly this fails as **doSomethingWith** method gets undefined parameter value. Thus I get the following error:

```
Can't interpolate {{doSomethingWith(myform.myinput)}} TypeError: $element is undefined
```

Where $element is the name of the parameter expected by doSomethingWith method.

Comment: Can you share your directive definition. The attribute value could be my-directive="doSomethingWith(myform.myinput)"

Comment: No, this is treated as a normal text then. It has to be wrapped inside the brackets. The directive isn't mine - it's from bootstrap angular components - please check data-tooltip-html-unsafe directive. But I don't think it would help since it works on other elements.